# Getting socket connection timeout with localhost android

Tags: java, php, android, sockets, serversocket

I have created one api in local host using php. This as I test in postman its working well but when I am calling in the url from android its giving an exception of socket connection time out.

Its ampps server, not able to connect.

This is my php script:

```
    <?php

//echo error
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// require database
require 'database.php';

//get file input
$jsonText = file_get_contents('php://input');

//check params in file
if (empty($jsonText)) {
    $response = array("status" => -1, "message" => "Empty request");
    die(json_encode($response));
}

try{

//decode params in json
$json = json_decode($jsonText);
$mobile_no = $json->mobile_no;
$device_id = $json->device_id;

//init database connection
$database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST, Constants::DBUSER, Constants::DBPASS, Constants::DBNAME);
$dbConnection = $database->getDB();

//query to insert device

$statement = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO data(mobile_number, device_id)
    VALUES(:mobile_no, :device_id)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "mobile_no" => $mobile_no,
    "device_id" => $device_id
));
    $newId = $dbConnection->lastInsertId();

    if($newId != null)
    {
        $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success");
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Constants:

```
<?php

class Constants
{
    const DBNAME = 'UserDevices';
    const DBUSER = 'fsdfsf';
    const DBPASS = 'fsdfsdfs';
    const DBHOST = '192.168.44.1';
}

?>
```

database

```
    <?php
require 'constants.php';

class Database
{

    private $dbhost;
    private $dbuser;
    private $dbpass;
    private $dbname;


    function Database($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname)
    {
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
        $this->dbpass = $dbpass;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;

    }

    function getDB()
    {

        $mysql_conn_string = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname;charset=utf8";

        try {
            $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_conn_string, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {

            echo($ex->getMessage());
        }

        return $dbConnection;
    }
}

?>
```

android

```
    String token = tokenPreference.getString("token","");

    if(!token.equals("")) {
        //String cno=preferences.getString("cono",null);
        String[] keys = new String[] {"mobile_no", "device_id"};
        String[] values = new String[] {preferences.getString(Const.DRIVER_MOBILE_NUMBER,""), token};

        final String jsonRequest = SecondUtils.createJsonRequest(keys, values);

        String URL = "http://192.168.44.1/fuelOneTest/insertDevice.php";



        new WebserviceCall(MainDriver.this, URL, jsonRequest, "Loading", true, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(String response) {
                Log.d("myapp", response);

                //     Toast.makeText(RegisterDriver.this, model.getResponse_desc(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    // change below condition to 0.. for testing it change to 1
                    if (jsonObject.get("message").equals("Success")) {

                        Log.d("DeviceToken", "Device token inserted.");

                    } else {

                    }
                }catch (JSONException je)
                {
                    je.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).execute();
    }

public class WebserviceCall extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
// interface for response

AsyncResponse delegate;
private final MediaType URLENCODE = MediaType.parse("application/json;charset=utf-8");
ProgressDialog dialog;
Context context;
String dialogMessage;
boolean showDialog = true;
String URL;
String jsonBody;

public WebserviceCall(Context context, String URL, String jsonRequestBody, String dialogMessage, boolean showDialog, AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.context = context;
    this.URL = URL;
    this.jsonBody = jsonRequestBody;
    this.dialogMessage = dialogMessage;
    this.showDialog = showDialog;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    if(Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {


        if (showDialog) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage(dialogMessage);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

        else {

            Utils.showDialog(context, context.getString(R.string.networkWarning));

        }

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // creating okhttp client
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

   //   client.setConnectTimeout(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    // creating request body
    RequestBody body;
    if(jsonBody != null) {
        body = RequestBody.create(URLENCODE, jsonBody);
    }else{
        body = null;
    };

        // creating request
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .post(body)
                .url(URL)
                .build();

        // creating webserivce call and get response

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String res = response.body().string();
            Log.d("myapp", res);
            return res;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if(dialog != null && showDialog){
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    if(s != null){

        delegate.onCallback(s);
    }else{
        Log.d("myapp",getClass().getSimpleName()+": response null");
    }
}
```

}

why is it happening so? can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

You're not running the script on your Android device, are you?

The answer to that is most likely **no**. Meaning it isn't on `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`). Find the internal IP (`192.168.x.x`) of the device that actually has the script and connect to that instead.

The socket timeout is because it can't connect to the Android device because there's nothing there.

Comment: yes I am testin on my device, but I am using the same net provider as the desktop on device using wifi

Comment: @Sid so?? Localhost is the **device itself**. That's why you need the internal IP. The internal IP is the location it has when connected to a given router, and that IP is always `192.168.x.x`. If I told you my internal IP was 192.168.1.101, you wouldn't be able to connect to it because we're on a different network. If the devices are connected to different networks you need the external IP (any numbers in the 0-255 range with the exception of localhost and internal IPs). You can't connect to localhost unless the script is on the same device

Comment: You should really read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/321734/how-does-localhost-127-0-0-1-work) related to how localhost works

Comment: how to check ip of device

Comment: As i used my device ip now its showing failed to connect,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161857/discussion-between-sid-and-zoe).

Answer (score 0):

If you try connecting via android emulator you must use 10.0.2.2 ip.

Via genymotion - 10.0.3.2.

If you use hardware device with mobile internet you must to know your pc ip in internet, for example use: https://2ip.ru/

If you use wi-fi check ip your pc in your net via "ipconfig" command at console

For connecting with socket you also must to know port that your server used